# Error: "Failed to get convolution algorithm." by TrackNet

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run **TrackNet's** neural network.
[Youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IVUyhMkyms&t=5s
[Repository]https://nol.cs.nctu.edu.tw:234/open-source/TrackNet/

```
Ubuntu: 16.04
CUDA: 10.0
cuDNN: 7.4.2
Tensorflow-GPU: 1.13.1 (by pip)
Python: 3.5
```

I checked my Tensorflow installed properly by running a tutorial succesfully.

However, when I try to run `predict_video.py`, it throws an error,

```
2020-02-05 15:39:18.115954: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:334] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-02-05 15:39:18.124059: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:334] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict_video.py", line 117, in <module>
    pr = m.predict(np.array([X]))[0]
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1462, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 324, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3076, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File ".../ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
```

Below is `tensorflow/python/client/session.py`

```
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # TODO(b/74355905): Support argument and return value nested structures,
      # and tensor-like objects such as SparseTensors.
      run_metadata = kwargs.get('run_metadata', None)
      try:
        run_metadata_ptr = tf_session.TF_NewBuffer() if run_metadata else None
        # TODO(mrry): Switch to raising an exception from the SWIG wrapper.
        with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
          ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
              self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
(1439)        run_metadata_ptr)
        if run_metadata:
          proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
          run_metadata.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(proto_data))
      finally:
        if run_metadata_ptr:
          tf_session.TF_DeleteBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
      return ret
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you do not have a compatibility between CUDA + CUDNN + TensorFlow version.

You will need to check this site for Linux compatibility in order to verify which exact version of CUDA + CUDNN + TensorFlow you need:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations

Comment: I did follow the requirement. `tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1` requires cuDNN 7.4 and CUDA 10.0. Should I build from source instead of using pip?

Comment: No. No need to. Try updating to Tensorflow 1.14. I used CUDA 10.0 + CUDNN 7.6.3 + TensorFlow 1.14 and it was a fully working combination.

Comment: Sounds promising! I'll come back tomorrow to share the result

Comment: Did you try with the new configuration?

Comment: Tensorflow 1.14 didn't fix the issue. I tried the code on Jetson Nano and it worked. Maybe I should switch to Ubuntu 18 and try again.